# How to install Git 2.11 from Source on mac

Tags: git, github, installation, open-source

I've tried to install the newest version of git from the source but with no success. My current version is 2.10 and I installed it with

```
sudo port install git
```

What I've been trying so far:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
```

into my Documents folder. Then:

```
make prefix=/usr profile
make prefix=/usr PROFILE=BUILD install
```

That's an error I get:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcov
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [git-credential-store] Error 1
make: *** [profile] Error 2
```

But there's no errors when I use:

```
make
make install
```

But I recon there's more to it than jus simply going `make` and `make install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first uninstall your Git then

use **[homebrew](http://brew.sh/)** to install the latest version of Git

```
brew update
brew install git
```

restart your terminal

;) Congrats you have the latest Git version

Comment: Can I install the latest version with homebrew already? Because I've done exactly what you've suggested this afternoon and it didn't work :(

Comment: can you uninstall the old rails and ruby then install again?

Comment: @carrotcake yes install the latest version of homebrew as well.